# CheckedListBox DataSource suddenly not working

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a CheckedListBox that used this code to get the items.

```
public static void GetDisplayValueList(object clk, string[] kv, string tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            string list = "";
            foreach (string item in kv)
               list += item + ",";
            string query = "SELECT " + list.Substring(0, list.Length - 1) + " FROM [dbo].[" + tableName + "]";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ((CheckedListBox)clk).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ((CheckedListBox)clk).DisplayMember = "Description";
            ((CheckedListBox)clk).ValueMember = "Id";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " + ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Suddenly, it doesn't work anymore and gives the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

What can I do to fix this, or is there any other way how to bind a CheckedListBox to a DataTable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your ds is null check why and fix it. You can use debug !

Comment: You haven't shown enough code. Where does `ds.Tables[0]` get populated? It's currently empty which is why you get the error.

Comment: @RoxhensMeraj Maybe because your Select query is not returning any results.

Comment: Off the top of my head your select statement won't work because of the trailing comma on the list of columns. You have `select column1, column2, column3, from table`. You need to remove the last comma. Provided the column names and table name are correct the rest looks fine.

Comment: nope, the query is ok, and ds.Tables[0] shows the correct data when I debug, but it just does not bind to the control ( at this row: `((CheckedListBox)clk).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` )

Comment: Well either `clk` or `ds.Tables[0]` is null for you to get that error.

Comment: Where does it give you the error? Place a breakpoint at the beginning of the `try` block an loop until the catch-block is hit.

Comment: FWIW: I ran up against the exact same error. Apparently the `CheckedListBox` object internally throws (and handles?) the error upon assignment of the `DataSource` property with a `List<KeyValuePairs<string,string>>`. That said,[when ignoring the error] things work perfectly fine. It's too bad the error is now ignored in the entire debugging session as it's kind of an important one.

Comment: Have the same behaviour suddenly, on code that works for a long time. Nothing changed on the project in my opinion.... weird

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I'll provide an answer, but I would help you improve some of the code-lines.

Getting a string from an array, seperated with any seperator:

```
string list = string.Join(",", kv);
```

If a string will become a bit messed-up with al the `+` operators:

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [dbo].[{1}]", list, tableName);
// Or
string query = $"SELECT {list} FROM [dbo].[{tableName}]"
```

To improve speed and performance, try to cast only once:

```
var clb = (CheckedListBox)clk;
clb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
clb.DisplayMember = "Description";
clb.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, when placing a breakpoint where you said, it breaks at this line of code `clb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` and when I click **Step Into (F11)** once and then **Continue** it works. To me it seems like `clb` throws the NullReferenceException, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Did you check if `ds.Tables[0]` is not null and has elements with properties `Description` and `Id`? Maybe it helps to set first `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` and then `DataSource`.

Comment: When is your method called? Is your form completely rendered?

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments on answers, I think you need to go higher up in your call stack.

You say the original error is on `((CheckedListBox)clk).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`. This means `clk` is `null`, and can't be used after casting to a `CheckedListBox`, since after the casting it's still `null`. (Note this doesn't mean `ds.Tables[0]` is null. A DataSource can be set to `null` to clear the data.)

Then after the changes from @Stef Geysels's answer, the error is on the line below.

```
var clb = (CheckedListBox)clk;     
clb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];    // <- error here
```

This further points out that `clk` is null, and when casting, `clb` is subsequently also `null`.

All that said, you need to check what is being passed in as `clk`

Comment: I agree with you, but how come that when I uncheck the **System.NullReferenceException** in **Exception Settings** the solution works fine? @CDspace